# FATAL EXCEPTION: main - app crashes after a while

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

For a long time am I facing a problem with xml parsing into Fragment NavigationTabs. When i run my project it appears for 2-4secs, doesn't view my listview (blank fragment) and than crashes. I think, that there is something wrong with onPostExecute method. Can I beg you for help?

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(473): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:271)
12-12 15:53:59.730: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.example.premierleague.clubsAdapter.<init>(clubsAdapter.java:37)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.example.premierleague.Fragment1$ClubsDownloadTask.onPostExecute(Fragment1.java:113)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.example.premierleague.Fragment1$ClubsDownloadTask.onPostExecute(Fragment1.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
12-12 15:53:59.730: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
private clubsAdapter mAdapter;
private ListView clubs;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    Log.i("PremierLeague", "OnCreateView()");




    clubs = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.clubsList);


    clubs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        Log.i("PremierLeague", "starting download Task");
        ClubsDownloadTask download = new ClubsDownloadTask();
        download.execute();
    }else{
        mAdapter = new clubsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), -1, 
                ClubsXmlPullParser.getItemsFromFile(getActivity()));
        clubs.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }   


    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}





//Helper method to determine if Internet connection is available.
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
          = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;





}

private class ClubsDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private clubsAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<LeagueClub> clubs;
    Fragment1 ctx;
    Context context = getActivity();
    private Context mContext;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {



        try {
            Downloader.DownloadFromUrl("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h2qc41k2yy3c1ir/clubs.xml", getActivity().openFileOutput("clubs.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        mAdapter = new clubsAdapter(mContext, -1, ClubsXmlPullParser.getItemsFromFile(getActivity()));
        ((ListView) clubs).setAdapter(mAdapter);
        Log.i("PremierLeague", "adapter size = "+ mAdapter.getCount());


    }

}


}
```

custom adapter

```
public class clubsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LeagueClub> {

ImageLoader imageLoader;
DisplayImageOptions options;



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public clubsAdapter(Context class1, int textViewResourceId, List<LeagueClub> clubs) {
    super(class1, textViewResourceId, clubs);

    //Setup the ImageLoader, we'll use this to display our images
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(class1).build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);

    //Setup options for ImageLoader so it will handle caching for us.
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .build();


}



    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stu


/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 * 
 * This method is responsible for creating row views out of a StackSite object that can be put
 * into our ListView
 */
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
    Log.i("PremierLeague", "getView pos = " + pos);
    if(null == row){
        //No recycled View, we have to inflate one.
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_site, null);
    }

    //Get our View References
    final ImageView clubLogo = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.clubLogo);
    TextView nameTxt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    TextView aboutTxt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.aboutTxt);
    TextView stadiumTxt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.stadiumTxt);
    final ProgressBar indicator = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress);

    //Initially we want the progress indicator visible, and the image invisible
    indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    clubLogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Setup a listener we can use to switch from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
    ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener(){



        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
            indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            clubLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View view, FailReason arg2) {
            indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.clubLogo);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    };

    //Load the image and use our options so caching is handled.
    imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(pos).getLogo(), clubLogo,options, listener);

    //Set the relevant text in our TextViews
    nameTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getName());
    aboutTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getAbout());
    stadiumTxt.setText(getItem(pos).getStadium());



    return row;


}

}
```

Comment: What line is number 37 in `clubsAdapter`?

Comment: +Ross Drew it is: super(class1, textViewResourceId, clubs);

Comment: I see.  See my answer then.  I've updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListView clubs = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.clubsList);
```

i fixed that problem with just adding the code above to onPostExecute.

Comment: This doesn't answer your original question though

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` is `null` when passed to your class `clubsAdapter` where it is used in the parent class `ArrayAdaptor` and throws a `NullPointerException`.  Possibly the `mContext` member of `ClubsDownloadTask`.

**Additionally**

Classes should start with a capitol letter: `ClubsAdapter` not `clubsAdapter`

Comment: Thanks for reply :) so what should i do?

Comment: Initialise `mContext` before passing it to `clubsAdapter`

Comment: im going to try it now.. will respond in few minutes :)

Comment: yeah.. opens for 3 secs and shuts down :/

Comment: nope, right now it is:  at com.example.premierleague.Fragment1$ClubsDownloadTask.onPostExecute(Fragment1.java:133) and: at com.example.premierleague.Fragment1$ClubsDownloadTask.onPostExecute(Fragment1.java:1) which is in my document: ((ListView) clubs).setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: i finally fixed it by simply adding this to onPostExecute: ListView clubs = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.clubsList);

Answer (score 0):

Change your onCreateView to following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    Log.i("PremierLeague", "OnCreateView()");




    clubs = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.clubsList);


    clubs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });



    return rootView;

}
```

also override this function:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      if(isNetworkAvailable()){
          Log.i("PremierLeague", "starting download Task");
          ClubsDownloadTask download = new ClubsDownloadTask();
          download.execute();
      }else{
          mAdapter = new clubsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), -1, 
                  ClubsXmlPullParser.getItemsFromFile(getActivity()));
          clubs.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      }   

}
```

The problem is in onCreateView getActivity returns null because this fragment is not yet attached to an activity.

You need to override onActivityCreated function and set adapter to your list in it.

Comment: Unluckily i get the same crash. I defined the context as: Context mContext; and pasted the corrections. Dont I have to create onAttach method for Fragment?

Comment: On what line r u getting this error now?? Yes u can putting adapter code into onAttach method as well that shud also work. Let me know if it works

Comment: In adapter am I getting error on line 37 which is: super(class1, textViewResourceId, clubs);